# Unit testing in spring mvc

Tags: spring, unit-testing, dao, resttemplate

If I want to unit test my dao classes in spring would I just call my service methods and test those or would you test the service methods separately to the actual dao methods?

Also should I mock the dao calls or actually use an in memory database like H2? I see that as more of an integration test although some tutorials do this, or would a standard approach be to test with mock database objects for the service tests and use H2 when testing the dao calls?

Finally.. My application has a rest API which is called from the web front end using the Spring rest template and so only the API web app accesses the database.

Would I test the rest methods in each web app using mocked objects and then Start a tomcat instance and integration test between the 2 apps? If I used tomcat and ran integration tests between the apps would connect up a database or mock objects in the API app?

Testing the rest calls from the web app relies really on how the API app's rest method responds so is this even worth testing in isolation?

I find unit testing quite confusing as some of it seems almost to be integration testing.

Does it matter if you run integration tests against H2 in memory but then in reality I would be using MySQL?

Comment: I personally would just use Spring Data and avoid implementing and testing my own DAO classes entirely.

Comment: @chrylis: That's a pretty big assumption that Spring Data would fit OPs use-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to answer your questions in the order asked...

For unit testing DAO methods, you should test the actual DAO classes directly with a database in a known state.  H2 is great for this, since you can run it without setting up MySQL for each test.  Utilizing setup methods with the `@Before` annotation is great to make sure that the database will respond in expected ways.

For unit testing Service classes, you should mock the DAO classes, so that they will always behave in expected ways.  If you use your service and DAO classes with actual data, you are now running integration tests, by testing multiple layers simultaneously.  Both have their value, though is generally best to unit test before integration testing, to make sure each component is functioning.

The same goes for testing your controller, you should unit test it and mock the service classes, and then perform integration tests with mock requests to test request/response scenarios.  Again, with this test setup you are now testing many layers and classes simultaneously.  This is great, because it gives you a good idea of how your application will function in reality, but is not useful for isolating bugs.

H2 and MySQL obviously are not the same, and don't share all the same functionality, so you can't say with 100% confidence that an H2 test will pass in MySQL, but if you are just testing standard CRUD operations, it should do the trick.

Comment: thanks that is really useful. It answers almost everything, what is your take on integration testing between web apps which are separate maven modules, is it worth having a tomcat started up as part of testing? The flow would be web app controller >> web app service (restTemplate) >> web API Controller >> web API service >> Web API DAO >> hibernate. Is it worth automating testing of the call from the web front end to the API back end, this would test many layers in one go? I will mark yours as the answer as it was exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: IMHO, the more layers you can test at once the better, that includes throwing Tomcat in there, if possible.  It gives you a better idea of how the app will function IRL.  That should not be a substitute for unit testing, though.